# loop http client python , twisted

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.web

I have A simple Client which sends a request to server and receives a response :

```
 from StringIO import StringIO

 from twisted.internet import reactor
 from twisted.internet.protocol import Protocol
 from twisted.web.client import Agent
 from twisted.web.http_headers import Headers
 from twisted.internet.defer import Deferred
 from twisted.web.client import FileBodyProducer

 import log , time

class server_response(Protocol):
     def __init__(self, finished):
         self.finished = finished
         self.remaining = 1024 * 10

     def dataReceived(self, bytes):
         if self.remaining:
            reply = bytes[:self.remaining]
            print "reply from server:" , reply
            log.info(reply)

     def connectionLost(self, reason):
          #print 'Finished receiving body:', reason.getErrorMessage()
          self.finished.callback(None)

def capture_response(response): 

    finished = Deferred()
    response.deliverBody(server_response(finished))
    return finished

def cl():

    xml_str = "<xml>"
    agent = Agent(reactor)
    body = FileBodyProducer(StringIO(xml_str))
    d = agent.request(
        'PUT',
        'http://localhost:8080/',
        Headers({'User-Agent': ['Replication'],
                'Content-Type': ['text/x-greeting']}),
        body)

    d.addCallback(capture_response)

    def cbShutdown(ignored):
        reactor.stop()

   d.addBoth(cbShutdown)
       reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':

     count = 1
     while (count < 5) :
     print count
     cl()
     time.sleep(2)
     count = count + 1
```

here in main, i am trying to send the request to server by invoking `cl()` 5 times in a `while loop` . but i am receiving some error, what i am assuming is that i have not stopped the `client` hence reactor is not starting, how do i solve this problem

Comment: plz tell us exactly what error you are getting.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connecting twice with twisted - how to do that correctly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979112/connecting-twice-with-twisted-how-to-do-that-correctly)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the Twisted reactor [cannot be restarted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#WhycanttheTwistedsreactorberestarted). Once you have done `reactor.stop()` you cannot do `reactor.start()` again.

Instead you need to do something like chaining the runs so that the callback for one run finishing will cause the next run to be started, or then schedule the runs with `reactor.callLater()`.

Comment: It's not that unfortunate - the fortunate thing is that nothing about this use-case would *require* restarting the reactor :).  This is one of the reasons we've gone so long without adding that feature - almost everyone who wants it is actually trying to do something else, where restarting the reactor would be actively harmful to their application's performance and correctness.

Comment: @Glyph, you are absolutely correct. The only time I didn't really find a workaround was when, as a complete Twisted noob, I wanted to write library code that could be called both from within a Twisted app and from a synchronous python program. I gathered that deferred/callback based code could easily be turned synchronous, while synchronous code cannot magically be used in Twisted without threading. I hacked together a small wrapper that started the reactor, ran the Twisted stuff and in the last callback/errback stopped reactor. It worked perfectly, once :-).