# How to to restart reactor of twisted and deluge client rpc

Tags: python, twisted

Im having problems at work with the twisted framework, I can't restart.
My code needs to connect to different deluged clients daemon in some different nodes. To do this i need to disconnect first, but twisted doesn't allow me to re-connect to another client.
These is my code:

```
    ip = ['localhost', 'debci-lab']
    for i in range(len(ip)):
    ip_connect = ip[i]
    d = client.connect(host=ip_connect)
    # We create a callback function to be called upon a successful connection
    def on_get_config(result):
    print result

    def on_connect_success(result):
        print "Connection was successful!"
        print "result:", result
        client.core.get_torrent_status('dd69058c737d914c4e8e985d47a29606de80d34e', ['download_payload_rate']).addCallback(on_get_config)
        client.disconnect()
    # We add the callback to the Deferred object we got from connect()
    d.addCallback(on_connect_success)

    # We create another callback function to be called when an error is encountered
    def on_connect_fail(result):
        print "result:", result

    # We add the callback (in this case it's an errback, for error)
    d.addErrback(on_connect_fail)

    reactor.run()
```

The loop only works one time, and outputs this:
Connection was successful!
result: 10

But not the download_rate expected.

Thank you for your time.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reactor is not restartable.  You call `reactor.run()` once.  You can establish as many connections as you like while the reactor is running.  You call `reactor.stop()` on when you're ready for the program to exit.

See also [Connecting twice with twisted - how to do that correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979112/connecting-twice-with-twisted-how-to-do-that-correctly)

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me using `reactor.crash()` for loop, `reactor.start()` do something, stop and repeat . . .

```
def main(myrequest):
    print myrequest
    data=[]
    errors=[]

    def got_data(mydata):
        data.append(mydata)
        process()

    def no_data(err):
        print >>sys.stderr, 'failed:', err
        errors.append(err)
        process()

    def process():
        if errors or data:
            reactor.crash()

    make_request("localhost", 9000, got_data, no_data, myrequest)

    return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bbg=["DBK GY EQUITY","IBM US Equity"]
    flds=["DVD_HIST"]
    for b in bbg:
        myrequest=bulk(b , flds)
        print ">>>>>>>>>>>>>>", main(myrequest)
```