# Twisted Reactor not restarting in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, python-telegram-bot

I'm trying to run a scrapy spider via a Telegram bot using the `python-telegram-bot` API wrapper. Using the below code, I can successfully execute the spider and forward the scraped results to the bot, but only ONCE since I run the script. When I attempt to re-execute the spider via the bot (telegram bot command), I get the error `twisted.internet.error.ReactorNotRestartable`.

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from scrapy import cmdline
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters, RegexHandler
import logging
import os
import ConfigParser
import json
import textwrap
from MIS.spiders.moodle_spider import MySpider
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner, CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging


# Read settings from config file
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('./spiders/creds.ini')
TOKEN = config.get('BOT', 'TOKEN')
#APP_NAME = config.get('BOT', 'APP_NAME')
#PORT = int(os.environ.get('PORT', '5000'))
updater = Updater(TOKEN)

# Setting Webhook
#updater.start_webhook(listen="0.0.0.0",
#                      port=PORT,
#                      url_path=TOKEN)
#updater.bot.setWebhook(APP_NAME + TOKEN)

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s -# %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s',level=logging.INFO)

dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

# Real stuff

def doesntRun(bot, update):
    #process = CrawlerProcess(get_project_settings())
    #process.crawl(MySpider)
    #process.start()
    ############

    configure_logging({'LOG_FORMAT': '%(levelname)s: %(message)s'})
    runner = CrawlerRunner({
        'FEED_FORMAT' : 'json',
        'FEED_URI' : 'output.json'
        })

    d = runner.crawl(MySpider)
    d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
    reactor.run(installSignalHandlers=0) # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
    #reactor.stop()

    with open("./output.json", 'r') as file:
        contents = file.read()
        a_r = json.loads(contents)
        AM = a_r[0]['AM']
        ...
        ...

        message_template = textwrap.dedent("""
                AM: {AM}
                ...
                """)
        messageContent = message_template.format(AM=AM, ...)
        #print messageContent
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text=messageContent)
        #reactor.stop()


# Handlers
test_handler = CommandHandler('doesntRun', doesntRun)

# Dispatchers
dispatcher.add_handler(test_handler)

updater.start_polling()
updater.idle()
```

I'm using the code from the docs: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script

Code goes like this:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your spider definition
    ...

configure_logging({'LOG_FORMAT': '%(levelname)s: %(message)s'})
runner = CrawlerRunner()

d = runner.crawl(MySpider)
d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
reactor.run() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39946632/reactornotrestartable-error-in-while-loop-with-scrapy

Comment: the linked duplicate question doesn't even have a definitive answer. And it's using the `CrawlerProcess` as opposed to the use of `CrawlerRunner` in my code.

Comment: See if these help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979112/connecting-twice-with-twisted-how-to-do-that-correctly, https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2016/09/14/restarting-a-twisted-reactor/. The ideal way to do it would be to use scrapyd and schedule a scraper using the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I finally solved my problem.

the Python-telegram-bot API wrapper offers [an easy way to restart the bot.](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Code-snippets#simple-way-of-restarting-the-bot)

I simply put the lines:

```
time.sleep(0.2)
os.execl(sys.executable, sys.executable, *sys.argv)
```

at the end of the doesntRun() function. Now whenever I call the function via bot, it scrapes the page, stores the results, forwards the result, then restarts itself. Doing so allows me to execute the spider any number of times I want.